# Less mixins do not inherit classes

Tags: css, less

I'm new with Less.js, I need to reuse the `p.InputTitle` like my examples, but it is not working for me :( it is giving me an error. I read more about mixins and some people tell me that I can use 'Extend'. What is that?

Here My code :

```
.LoginForm {
    p.InputTitle {
        color: #656565;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-family: @OpenSans;
        font-weight: 600;
    }
}

.Membership{
    p.InputTitle {
      .LoginForm p.InputTitle;
    }
}
```

Comment: Here's more on extend http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Less [`extend`](http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature) pseudo class:

```
.Membership{
    p.InputTitle {
      &:extend(.LoginForm p.InputTitle);
    }
}
```

This will then produce:

```
.LoginForm p.InputTitle,
.Membership p.InputTitle {
  color: #656565;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

---

Your syntax is calling in the form of a mixin call and a mixin name cannot be `p.InputTitle`.

If you were to change your original `LoginForm` CSS to the following then this would act as a valid mixin:

```
.LoginForm {
    .InputTitle {
        color: #656565;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: 600;
    }
}
```

You could then write:

```
.Membership{
    p.InputTitle {      
        .LoginForm .InputTitle;
    }
}
```

However this would then produce double the amount of CSS styles:

```
.LoginForm .InputTitle {
  color: #656565;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.Membership p.InputTitle {
  color: #656565;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

Comment: i tried the online compiler and its working , Thanks . im using now the Simpless Compiler and its give me error :( its just give me the error line

Comment: The compiler Give me syntax  in this line

  p.InputTitle {
      &:extend (.LoginForm p.InputTitle);
    }

Comment: @MohamedSamy Most probably a bug in Simpless, or it supports an earlier version of Less. I recommend researching that.